# Do I need to install dry wall in my basement?

Tags: walls, concrete, basement

I have a concrete basement with concrete walls. I'm thinking about just painting the basement and not have to put up dry wall because I want to save money. Is that a good idea or should I really install the dry walls? My basement doesn't have a water problem.

My basement ceiling is also exposed with nails wire. I will need to cover that up. I will eventually install some type of flooring too.

Comment: just a thought, but if you are seeking to save money and just dress up the walls a bit, paint is a sure way to do that -- later if you want a more finished space, you can always add the drywall.  Rory has some good points as to why.  Check with your paint supplier for the best product for the task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What drywall will give you includes:

- Insulation. Concrete is not a good insulator, so drywall will help here, and as @ChrisF points out in the comment, you can add insulation behind drywall for some extra.
- Soundproofing. A bit of soundproofing, anyway
- Somewhere to run cables behind, so they aren't exposed. Depening on where you are this may be a requirement
- Simplified shelf mounting etc.
- Much easier to cover/paint - you can use normal paints on drywall

Comment: Don't forget that you can install insulation behind the drywall for added heat retention.

Comment: To your last point about being easier to cover/paint, it is also much, much cheaper. A 5 gallon bucket of concrete paint will cover a small area and cost $100. A 5 gallon bucket of regular latex drywall paint will cost slightly more but cover all the drywall in your basement with two coats and have half the bucket left over.